# Title reference of Pierce Brosnan James Bond movies

Tags: james-bond, title, reference

Reference for the title of the James Bond movies was either taken from the novels by Ian Fleming or the particular story element. For eg. GoldenEye, Octopussy etc.

GoldenEye refers to the satellite, Casino Royale refers to the poker game played in the movie, and Spectre refers to the criminal organization run by Blofeld. There are more examples.

However, I do not see any reference for movies, *Tomorrow Never Dies*, *The World Is Not Enough* and *Die Another Day*.

Where were the titles of these movies taken from?

**For the readers**

James Bond uses exactly these terms in his dialogue while talking to villain of the movies.

**Die Another Day**

> James Bond to Gustav Graves, "so you live to die another day."

**The World is Not Enough**

> **Electra:** I could've given you the world.
>
> **James:** The world is not enough.

Comment: Keep in mind, there are only so many Fleming written novels.  In order to keep Bond going, they had to create new stories.

Comment: yes i know, but I want to know the title reference.

Comment: And I'm saying there probably isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tomorrow never dies**

> The original title of the film was "Tomorrow Never Lies", which makes
> sense when you consider media mogul Elliot Carver (Jonathan Pryce) was
> creating the next day's headlines in advance, then causing those
> events to happen. But a typo on an early script draft was adopted by
> the producers, and "Tomorrow Never Dies" was used instead. Another
> rumour circulated that the film was originally going to be called
> "Tomorrow Never Comes". There are apparently video tapes that were in
> distribution when the film was released on video that do have the
> caption "Tomorrow Never Comes" at the very beginning of the tape, not
> the beginning of the movie.
>
> According to german wikipedia, this was inspired by the Beatles-Song Tomorrow Never Knows

**The World Is Not Enough**

> The only direct Fleming influence on the movie is its title, and even
> this can be taken as a continuity reference to the movie On Her
> Majesty's Secret Service. In the book of that name, "the world is not
> enough" is given as the motto of one Sir Thomas Bond, although there
> is no evidence that this is one of Bond's descendents. The literary
> Bond notes says somewhat sarcastically that he will adopt the motto,
> although in the movie version Bond seems to accept it without
> question. However, the movie does include M being kidnapped, an
> element which formed the basis for the first non-Fleming novel,
> "Colonel Sun" by Kingsley Amis (writing as Robert Markham), although
> in a different context.
>
> According to german wikipedia, Bond learns that the familly-motto is „Orbis non sufficit“, latin for „The World Is Not Enough“. In the movie Elektra tells bond that she could have offered him the whole world, but bond replies with his family-motto

**Die Another Day**

> According to german wikipedia, the phrase *die another day* is taken from the poem *The Day of
> Battle* from A. E. Housemans collection *A Shropshire Lad*. („But
> since the man that runs away lives to die another day“).

Sources:

German wikipedia [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond_007_%E2%80%93_Der_Morgen_stirbt_nie) [2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond_007_%E2%80%93_Die_Welt_ist_nicht_genug) [3](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond_007_%E2%80%93_Stirb_an_einem_anderen_Tag) ( I wonder why this is stated for all 3 movies there, but not in the english wiki)
[MI6-HQ](https://www.mi6-hq.com/sections/movies/dad)
[this page](http://www.mjnewton.demon.co.uk/bond/twine.htm)